# rails 3 using devise for authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise in my Rails 3 application for authentication.

My requirement is to use **Username** to login rather than **email**.

So I modified the **config/initializers/devise.rb** file as below

> config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]

Modified the `registraion` page to take username, email, password during registration.
Also modified signin, signup views to include username.

**My Issue:**

When I click on `Forgot password`, it shows me field to enter `email`. After I enter 'email' and click on button 'Send me reset password instructions'.

It throws an error `Username can't be blank`.

Where do I make changes to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would presume that authentication_keys set :username as a required field.

Try editing app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb, and replacing:

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
```

with:

```
<%= f.label :username %>
<br />
<%= f.text_field :username %>
```

Comment: Right, devise includes default views for its functions, but you have to override all of the ones you want to use if you change the primary login field.